# Show models where Rails engine's model are enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, rubygems

So i am working on a rails engine, which have `upload` and `validate` functions. once file is uploaded a user will click on validate and than it will save the data from excel file to app's table. My engine won't provide any migration, all migrations will be provided by the app.

Now when i mount my engine, my engine's model are needed to be registered in some of app's model. For e.g. if there are total 10 models and my engine's model are registered only in 3 models of app than it should show me on which models of app my engine's model are enabled.

Than also i should be able to access tables for those models in my engine to save data from excel file.

code for engine's model is

```
require "roo"

module MyEngine
  class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "admins"

    def self.validate(file)
      spreadsheet = open_excel(file)
      header = spreadsheet.row(1)
      for i in 2..spreadsheet.last_row do
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
        upload = Upload.new(row)
        upload.save!
      end
    end

    private

    def self.open_excel(file)
      case File.extname(file)
      when ".xls", ".xlsx" then Roo::Spreadsheet.open file
      else raise "File format not supported"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here as you can see that i have hardcoded to set the table name but its not possible to set table name everytime.
Any help would be appreciated. I am really frustrated and tired as i have been stuck on this problem from last two weeks. I am new to ruby and its first time for me when i am writing a engine.

Comment: anymore details on how you want to save the data to the models? any code on how the engine looks now?

Comment: yeah for now assuming that columns in app's table and excel file are same. Also i have updated the answer with code.

Comment: When you want to add functionality to an existing table, did you consider making your code a mixin instead of a model on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a some sort of communication between the engine and the hosting app models, many gems (*aka engine gems*) follow the **ActAsSomething** patern.

Here is an example just to point you to the direction (untested code):

```
require "roo"

module MyEngine
  module Uploadify
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods

    def acts_as_uploadifiable(options = {})

      #you can use a passed hash to control matching attribute names
      # acts_as_uploadifiable attributes: [attr1, attr2, ... etc]

      # to evaluate on model who called acts_as_uploadifiable
      class_eval do
        def self.validate(file)
          spreadsheet = open_excel(file)
          header = spreadsheet.row(1)
          for i in 2..spreadsheet.last_row do
            row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
            #not sure what you want to do here!
            upload = Upload.new(row)
            upload.save!
          end
        end

        private
          def self.open_excel(file)
            case File.extname(file)
            when ".xls", ".xlsx" then Roo::Spreadsheet.open file
            else raise "File format not supported"
            end
          end
      end
    end
  end
end
# make Uploadify module avaiable to all our models
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyEngine::Uploadify
```

I've found browsing other gems source code to be the best way to learn how to write engines. Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks @Nimir for reply and a well explained answer. So this code will be added in our `lib` folder ryt?

Comment: And after doing transpose i am creating a new instance variable and saving excel data to database. As i have set the table_name = 'admins' here.

Comment: @Sinscary yes, in `lib/my_engine.rb` for example

Comment: @Sinscary you could access the model instance using `self` inside the `class_eval` then add the data `self.create!(row)` if i understood correctly!

Comment: hey @Nimir i am having a problem. I am not able to get the table name. Should i make any changes in controller also. Right now i am calling `Upload.validate(file)` in controller which than accesses the validate method. But in that case i think instance of `upload` is being accessed. So how do i access app's model in engine's controller.